# Can't boot on a Gigabyte GA-770-D3L motherboard

Tags: boot, 11.10

I have a gigabyte GA-770-D3L MOTHERBAORD and my first hdd is SSD OCZ 120gbytes , I can't boot ubuntu ! Not even tries to load it!

Is my motherboard incompatible? Its very strange.

- I have set the boot order all right
- It doesn't even get me to the grub
- When I install windows it's booting normally.
- cd rom boots like a charm but hdd refuse to proceed to booting.
- I tried to disable the efi boot on bios (its for windows 7 64bit) but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to boot ubuntu from the cd, from the usb or from the hard disk?
if its from the cd, could be the boot order from the bios that isn't correct
if its from the usb, it might be the iso from the usb that's not working correctly
the 3rd option cant help

Comment: I can't boot ubuntu 11.10 from my hard disk (mentioned above)  It doesn't even get me to the grub !!! When i install windows its booting normally. I don't know what is going on but something is really strange. Linux incompatible motherboard??? Motherboard that runs only windows?? What is going on ?

Comment: cd rom boots like a charm but hdd refuse to proceed to booting. I tried to disable the efi boot on bios (its for windows 7 64bit) but it made no difference. Please help its something about my motherboard i never had problems booting ubuntu. I'm so desperate that i've installed windows

Comment: Something about the cable order was wrong, also ive changed the cable after a month cause it had problems and now everything its ok.